# How to get rid of mixed content warning when using cookie-less domain for static content?

Tags: domains, https, cookie, mixed-content-security

When I serve all website content from same domain (`https://example.com`), tools like pingdom keeps yelling:

> Serve static content from a cookieless domain

When I serve static content from cookie-less domain (`http://cdn.example.com`), Chrome says:

> Mixed Content: The page at '`https://example.com/`' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   '`http://cdn.example.com/img/xyz.jpg`'. This content should also be
>   served over HTTPS.

How can I satisfy both conditions at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I serve static content from cookie-less domain (`http://cdn.example.com`)

Just as the message says... Your "cookie-less domain" also needs to be HTTPS. eg. `https://cdn.example.com`.

Once you switch to HTTPS then *everything* must switch to HTTPS. It's all or nothing. This is for a reason... If you have resources on a non-secure HTTP connection then it is possible that "information" could be leaked over this non-secure connection and intercepted, which kind of defeats the point of having HTTPS in the first place.

Comment: so what does the _Serve static content from a cookieless domain_ mean?

Comment: By using a different host/domain to serve your static content then the "marginal" overhead of the browser unnecessarily responding to and sending `Cookie:` headers (that are associated with your main site) is avoided. However, bear in mind, that you can't use a subdomain like `cdn.example.com` as a cookie-less domain, if you are using the apex domain (eg. `example.com`) for you main site. You would need to use `www.example.com` (for example). (One of the _advantages_ of `www` over non-`www`.)

Comment: So, if I served static content from different domain like `mysupercdn.net`, then the mixed content warning would disappear?

Comment: Yes, providing it is `https://mysupercdn.net` (note the HTTPS). The Mixed content warning is because you have both HTTPS (secure) and HTTP (non-secure) content on the same page.

Comment: Ah, so I think I got the point now. It's not a matter of HTTP vs HTTPS, it must be always HTTPS, just not setting cookies for static content requests. So I need the domain just because I am using https for `*.example.com`, therefore there are cookies being set for every subdomain. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. If you set a cookie on the apex domain eg. `example.com` then those same cookies are accessible to all subdomains as well. The "cookie-less domain" notice and the "mixed content warning" are two very different things, it's just that you seemed to "accidentally" jump from one the other. ("From the frying pan into the fire", as the saying goes.) The cookie-less domain thing is relatively minor when compared with the "mixed content" warning. The benefit of the cookie-less domain is dependent on how many/large cookies you are setting and the number of resources being requested.